# Monogame Xamarin on Mac show this error . This add-in can't be loaded due to missing dependencies.

Tags: macos, xamarin, monogame

[image: this is error after i installed Xamarin and monogame]

how to fix this issue. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The add-in does not support MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio 6.0. Stable support is coming, but still underway. The next MonoGame version (3.6) should be released soon, and will probably fix this. There are two options until then:

- Use MonoGame with MonoDevelop 5 until official support arrives.
- Try the [alpha version of the add-in](http://addins.monodevelop.com/Project/Index/47). This is not officially supported, but built by the MonoGame add-in maintainer.